# If $\bar{x}$ has a Burr distribution, what is the distribution of $x_{i}$?

Tags: distributions, mean

If $X=( x_{1},x_{2}, \cdots ,x_{n})$ $x_{i}$s are iid, and $\bar{x}$ has a Burr distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burr_distribution), what is the distribution of $x_{i}$, $i=1, \cdots ,n$.

Comment: What is the Burr distribution? Please provide a definition or link. Are the $x_i$ modeled as _independent_ random variables or are they dependent random variables?

Comment: You are going to need to give some more information to get a meaningful answer here, I think. For example ... what if they follow a joint distribution such that $x_1 = x_2 = \dots = x_n$ and $x_1$ follows a Burr distribution?

Comment: @DilipSarwate https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burr_distribution, my data are independent.

Comment: So why not _edit_ your question to include the link to the Burr distribution as well? By the way, it makes  no sense to say that $X$ is iid, it is the _collection_ $\{x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n\}$ of random variables that are iid.

Comment: @DilipSarwate done!

Comment: The characteristic function of $\bar x$ is $φ_{\bar x}(t) = \int_ℝ e^{itx}ckx^{c-1} / (1 + x^c)^{k + 1}   dx$. If this integral has a closed-form solution (which seems likely), you can take the *n*th root and there's the characteristic function of $x_i/n$.

Comment: @Kodiologist can you please explain how did you get this, do you have a reference?

Comment: @Enthusiastic I just plugged-and-chugged with [the definition of a characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_\(probability_theory\)#Definition) and the PDF of the Burr distribution. The *n*th root part comes from the fact that the characteristic function of a finite sum of independent random variables is the product of their characteristic functions.

Comment: @Kodiologist, the integration is pretty hard for me, could you please give me some hints on how to do it?

Comment: @ToneyShields I'm afraid I don't know how to do it myself. Otherwise, I would've posted an answer.